# Extjs widget Column with widget as button

Tags: extjs, widget

I have a situation where I need to disable the button(added as widget for widget column) when I receive one web socket event. When receiving  the web socket I might be in any page. So how to get the reference of that button widget and disable it.
I have created a fiddle  [WidgetTestFiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3a7f)
Can anyone please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure if this is because it's prototype code, but you should never use `record.data` directly when accessing properties like that... use [record.get](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/classic/Ext.data.Model.html#method-get) instead.

Comment: When you take a look in the source, record.get does the following: return this.data[fieldName] - i dont think "you should never" use is correct here. For simple models i think its Ok to use it like that, but of course you are right, using record.get will follow more the whole framework approach.

Comment: @devbnz, you're right, there are certain scenarios where you could possibly use it... if you don't want stores or anything to know the model's been updated, but getting a property, you should always use `get`.  Combined with the fact that the Ext.data.Model documentation doesn't show `data` anywhere in the list of properties/configs you can use.  So if you're just trying to be argumentative, that's cool.

Comment: You are totally right for associated models but for simple key value objects, like in this example, you can do it without problem. get or getData for the whole record data does nothing else or better nothing more. My intention with this comment was to share my experience and not saying you are wrong. If i would need to teach it, i would teach it like you said, striclty following the extjs way. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Ext.ComponentQuery](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/classic/Ext.ComponentQuery.html).

Using the query method you can search for the buttons inside your grid.

You probably want to give your buttons an `itemId` (e.g. itemId: 'widgetcolumn-button-switch') to ensure that you only find the buttons you want.

Using the `itemId` your search query would look like this: `'button[itemId="widgetcolumn-button-switch"]'`

I forked your fiddle and created my own version to illustrate my point: [Sencha fiddle example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3a7u)

Answer (score 0):

I think there are several ways to achieve your wanted result.

KaMuns answer  will work, but can be tricky in case you use a buffered store / grid. Because the pages in this case are handled internally by the store. Using a static itemId wont work in this case out of the box.

I would suggest you rely on the record data.

Everytime you recieve a websocket message, update the store and refresh the grid view can be an option.

I have modified your fiddle here:

- https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3a87

Here are is the most relevant part:

```
var grid = btn.up('grid');
var models =  grid.getStore().getData().getRange(); // of cause you can use find or another way here
var model = models.filter(mod => mod.get('actualRole') === 'Follower');
model[0].set('showBtn', false);
grid.getView().refresh(); // get ref to view and refresh because data changed
```

---

On top you can have a look on the defaultBindProperties and may change this to the hidden key of the button.